# Hot-spot detection in solar folder

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

How to detect hotspots in a solar PV folder. I do know that those points will be brighter than the normal points.

Input: A thermal image. The input image is as:

[image: input image]

How to approach this problem using IP to first find hot-spots and return co-ordinates of it?

Now I need to find the co-ordinates of the bright spots encircled (hot-spots) in this image. Later I need to predict the potential hot-spot as well.

Comment: You shall attach your image here..so that people can help you.

Comment: Odd that people have voted down this question. I do not see why that would be. It seems a reasonable question and the image is there

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far. It is not the goal of SO to solve your complete task. Start with some simple techniques such as thresholding.

Comment: Temperature images should not be analyzed as an RGB images, since the color map is a fake and does not tell you everything, it should be analyzed as a double mat with the temperatures value. Then you can threshold the desired temperatures. However the region to search of the pannels have to be detected normalizing to a greyscale and finding the lines of the panels

Comment: So, essentially you want me to convert the RGB image to grayscale first?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem too sure about which software you want to use as you have tagged your question with both **OpenCV** and **Matlab**, so I guess you are unsure.

So, you could consider using **Imagemagick** which is free and installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS (and Windows if you have to) with Python, Perl, PHP, .NET, Java, Ruby, C, C++ bindings available - see [ImageMagick website](http://imagemagick.org).

There is a script from Fred Weinhaus's (@fmw42) excellent website called `maxima`, which does much of what you require - it is [here](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/maxima/index.php). It uses and requires **ImageMagick**. I believe it is free for non-commercial use, but please respect the licensing.

So, just at the shell in Terminal, you could run the following, assuming your image is named `solar.jpg`:

```
./maxima -n 5 -r 20 -c red solar.jpg result.png
```

**Output**

```
max=1 342,187 gray=61045.7,238,93.1498%
max=2 354,228 gray=60383,235,92.138%
max=3 233,264 gray=57768,225,88.149%
max=4 196,106 gray=56295,219,85.9%
```

The -r 20 ignores all peaks within a radius of 20 pixels from any other, the -n 5 says you want to find 5 peaks. In the output, you can see the coordinates of the peaks and their brightness and they are marked on in red here:

[image]

It appears to find one peak less than you ask for - may be a buglet :-)

Comment: There is a stopping threshold in my script, maxima. So you may need to lower the threshold a bit to catch the next hot spot.

Comment: CONTINUED: Perhaps you want to limit it to finding two regions, since I see two hot spots that you have marked. In this case, set -n 2 and -t thresh to some value, if needed, so that you get at least both spots found. The script will find the brightest two of all it finds.

Comment: @fmw42 Mmm, if I change `n` to `4`, I get three dots. If I change `n` to `3` I get two dots. That doesn't seem consistent with a threshold - or have I misunderstood it and the threshold is relative to the previous maximum?

Comment: Mark, thanks for the observation. I checked the script and there was an error off by 1 in my looping index. I have fixed it and uploaded the script to my web site. Try it again. I also note that the threshold for stopping and the stopping distance are off by default. So you should now get as many maxima as you indicate by -n. The purpose of the threshold is to set it to some reasonable value to distinguish the hot spots from other slightly less bright areas, then set -n to some higher value than you expect or some large value. Then it will stop at presumably only the true number of hotspots

Comment: P.S. The script will allow you to start with a color image. Internally it will process the image to grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using ImageMagick, is to threshold the image to black/white to isolate the spots and use connected components labeling to locate the centroids or bounding boxes. For example since the spots are white, I can simply threshold the image. (But if the spots are some unique color, you can convert that color to white and all the rest to black):

```
convert Bm18f.jpg -auto-level -threshold 89% -type bilevel tmp2.png
```

[image]

```
convert tmp.png -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=5 -connected-components 8 null:

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 593x473+0+0 296.0,236.0 280330 gray(0)
  1: 15x15+341+177 346.9,184.8 112 gray(255)
  2: 8x7+351+224 354.9,227.2 47 gray(255)
```

The gray(0) is the black background and the gray(255) are the two white regions. The bounding box and centroid are listed along with the area of each region.

Note that I have discarded regions with areas smaller than 5 pixels to remove the 1 pixel black spot in the center of the smaller region (or any other small extraneous spots from the threshold if set a bit lower.

Comment: Thank-you very much for this help sir. Actually, I have  a large data set(around 1 lac such images). Doing the above operation reduces the 'n' which is input data for later process which is as folows:   1. After detecting those hot spots, I need to do certain operations on them. I need to classify them on the basis of shape (scattered or in whole cell), location(where in the folder i.e. bottom side or up side etc). and intensity (based on shading). Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should I use SVM classifiers or Neural nets to classify the obtained data. Also is there an efficient way(i.e.data structure) to store those hot spots data (n) say bins.

Comment: Plus I am not much familiar with Imagemagick. So can you help me run the same code in MATLAB?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know MATLAB.

Comment: It's Okay Sir. Can you still tell me the algorithmic approach to solve this problem specially the classification part.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick using my script maxima, as a follow-up to Mark's solution and after fixing the indexing bug (that he pointed out above), here is a version that sets a threshold and puts the number to a large value (10). But it stops at the threshold and finds the two hot spots.

```
maxima -n 10 -t 90 -r 17 -c red solar.jpg solar_maxima.png
```

[image]