# How to get position of brightest points on the panel from a video by OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

guys, here is the problem: I want to locate some brightest points on the panel from a video, as shown in the picture, assumeing there is no red '+H', 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try segmenting by color. The `Lab` colorspace (along with others) give a luminosity channel which is roughly the brightness, so you can threshold on that channel. Or you can try simply converting to grayscale and thresholding to at least see what you can get.

Comment: Please also post an image without the annotation else it makes it hard to test algorithms.

Comment: This is extremely similar... https://stackoverflow.com/q/44412595/2836621

Comment: I have only these kind of images, I can get the brightest points by threshold, but I can hardly caculate  the column of PV panel where the brightest points lie on. After I get these points, I may not get a whole PV panel, so I don't know its location

Answer (score 0):

These are what I did, now I want to try 'Panoramic stitching' to get a whole PV panel, I don't know if I am going the wrong way:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]